# Version issue with change from .net 4.5.2 to 4.0 in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have an .edmx file which includes a lot of tables. The file is inside a project created with .NET 4.5.2. But my other projects are using .NET version 4.0 and i can not refer this project. I have to change my used .NET version to 4.0. But it gives me an error below while rebuild process. I can not solve this.

> The primary reference "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built
>   against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher
>   version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

Comment: Yeah so reinstall the package.

Comment: Which one? Entity framework or my tables?

Comment: Are your tables a package? I mean the Entity Framework package.

Comment: I tried before reinstall EF and nothing happen.

Comment: Do you understand your problem? Your current project compiles to .net 4.0, You refernced a DLL that must be compiled on top of .net 4.5 (the entity framework refernce).  One of the solutions would be to use a .net 4.0 refernce of entity framework package. There are other solutions possible

Comment: Not just re-install, you got to make sure the target EF package compiles to .net 4.0

Comment: As suggested in the answers, using the right reference (net40) is the way to go. However, I think it's worth noting that an alternative (and more involved) way of fixing this would be to upgrade the other projects to 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall EF6 using nuget as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

Go to `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console`
Then type `Update-Package -Id EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0 –reinstall`

You might need to edit your packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" />

    <!-- ... -->
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1):

EF has both a net40 folder and a net45 folder. You are most likely referencing the dll in net45. If you uninstalled the package and reinstalled as CodeCaster suggested, then you may have a stuck reference in your csproj file. You can try this:

1. Right click your web project and choose "Unload Project". Now you can right click and edit it.
2. Look for the reference path and if it says \net45 change it to \net40
3. Right click and reload project.

`<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">`

`<HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>` 
`<Private>True</Private>`

`</Reference>`

Comment: Something else that works for me when it comes to stuck references is to 1) remove the reference, 2) close VS, 3) delete the SUO file, 4) launch VS again and 5) add the reference to the project.

Comment: Yes, I usually follow a similar sequence (reinstall, manually change reference, clean, delete the .suo). Some solution settings like startup project need to be reset after.